# Calculating seasonal indices for the stock market: How to code for market closures?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a small program to calculate seasonal indices for stocks. It uses a simple data file like this:

```
2/17/1995,481.97
2/21/1995,482.74
2/22/1995,485.07
2/23/1995,486.91
2/24/1995,488.11
2/27/1995,483.81
2/28/1995,487.39
```

Here is the program:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        newSeasonal
# Purpose:     calculate a seasonal index
#
# Author:      John Bollinger
#
# Created:     07/12/2020
# Copyright:   (c) John Bollinger 2020
# Licence:     MIT
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# python 3.6.1+ required
# import the packages we will need
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

def main(datapath, datafile, start, stop, nonTradeDays):
    # read file and store recent changes
    df = pd.read_csv(datapath + datafile, parse_dates=True, names = ["date","close"], index_col = 0)
    # correct for market closures
    for day in nonTradingDays:
         pass
    # create a dataframe to hold the results
    seasonal = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(1,253))
    for col in range(start, stop):
        seasonal[col] = np.nan
    # populate the dataframe
    for year in range(start, stop):
        date_ = datetime.date(year, 1, 2)
        j = 1
        while (date_.year == year):
            try:
                seasonal.loc[j, year] = df.loc[date_].close
                j += 1
                date_ += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            except KeyError:
                date_ += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    # index the years to 100
    for year in range(start, stop):
        seasonal[year] = seasonal[year]/seasonal.loc[1, year]*100
    # plot the results
    plotTitle = "S&P 500 Annual Seasonal Trading Pattern 2000 through 2019"
    ax = seasonal[1:252].mean(axis=1, skipna = True).plot(title = plotTitle)
    ax.set_xlabel("trading days")
    ax.set_ylabel("composite seasonal")
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datapath = "c:\\Users\Public\\Portfolio\\Python Scripts\\newSeasonal\data\\"
    datafile = "spx.csv"
    start = 2000
    stop = 2020
    # special non-trading days 1990 through 2020
    # Nixon     4/27/1994
    # 9/11      9/11-14/2001
    # Reagan    6/11/2004
    # Ford      1/2/2007
    # Sandy     10/29-30/2012
    # HW Bush   12/5/2018
    nonTradeDays = ["1994-04-27", "2001-09-11", "2001-09-12", "2001-09-13", \
        "2001-09-14", "2004-06-11", "2007-01-02", "2012-10-29", \
        "2012-10-30", "2018-12-05"]
    main(datapath, datafile, start, stop, nonTradeDays)

#  That's all folks!
```

My problem is this, special non-trading days cause lineup problems so I would like to insert a row for each special day containing the value from the previous day. Like this

```
6/10/2004, aaaa.aa
6/12/2004, bbbb.bb
```

Becomes

```
6/10/2004, aaaa.aa
6/11/2004, aaaa.aa
6/12/2004, bbbb.bb
```

I have a list of the missing dates and have tried various strategies such as append with reindexing, concat, and setting with enlargement without success. My question is: What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pandas DatetimeIndex on your dataframe (i.e. setting your dataframe index to the values in the date column), you could concatenate this with an empty dataframe made up from your special non-trading days (as another DatetimeIndex), then finally forward fill the NaNs:

```
# Example dataframe, df:

#                   Open        High         Low       Close    Volume
# Date                                                                
# 2020-11-16  118.919998  120.989998  118.150002  120.300003  91183000
# 2020-11-18  118.610001  119.820000  118.000000  118.029999  76322100
# 2020-11-20  118.639999  118.769997  117.290001  117.339996  73391400

# Special days:

special_days = ['2020-11-17', '2020-11-19']

special_days_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime(special_days))

pd.concat([df,special_days_df],axis=0).sort_index().fillna(method='ffill')

#                   Open        High         Low       Close    Volume
# Date                                                                
# 2020-11-16  118.919998  120.989998  118.150002  120.300003  91183000
# 2020-11-17  118.919998  120.989998  118.150002  120.300003  91183000
# 2020-11-18  118.610001  119.820000  118.000000  118.029999  76322100
# 2020-11-19  118.610001  119.820000  118.000000  118.029999  76322100
# 2020-11-20  118.639999  118.769997  117.290001  117.339996  73391400
```

Comment: To skip the future warning: pd.concat([df, nonTrade_days_df], axis = 0, sort =True ).sort_index().fillna(method = 'ffill')